# How can I detect if a video is full screen using JS/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, video, html5-video

I've been looking everywhere and I haven't found something that is clear enough yet.

*(Please note most answers out there are so outdated I believe there must be a better way.)*

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Upon entering full screen, `<video>` tags are unmuted.
2. Upon exiting full screen, `<video>` tags are muted.

Please understand I have multiple `<video>` tags in one page, and they are dynamically generated.

What would be ideal, is a **JS/JQuery event** which listens to all of the `<video>` tags for events, and if the screen mode changes, it toggles the mute mode.

Imagine my video tags are:

```
<video class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block rounded " src="something.mp4" controls muted loop alt="Article Video">
<video class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block rounded " src="something-else.mp4" controls muted loop alt="Article Video">
```

The JQuery for toggling I believe is something like this:

```
var video = $('.some-video-class');
video.muted = !video.muted;
```

But I cannot find anywhere how to listen for full screen events, I suppose it would be something like this:

```
video.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', function(video){
    var video = $('.some-video-class');
    video.muted = !video.muted;
});
```

If someone could help me out and figure out what I'm doing wrong that would be much appreciated.

*Please note I am using Bootstrap **4.3.1** and JQuery **3.4.1***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to work you need to listen for the `fullscreenchange` event (including the vendor-specific versions). Then you can use the `document.fullscreenElement` property to determine which video which is currently fullscreen and amend the `muted` property accordingly. Try this:

```
$('video').on('fullscreenchange webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange', function() {
  this.muted = document.fullscreenElement !== this;
});
```

This will work for any `video` element you have on your page.

Here's a working example in a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0rqwo6p1/), which is required as SO snippets disallow fullscreen video.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Additionally, if anyone is having the same issue, and your videos are being added from an ajax request - make sure to include this inside `ajax.done(function(){ //here })`. Thank you for your help Rory.